# how do implement action on switch with Material (CosmicMind)

Tags: ios, xcode, cosmicmind

i'm trying to add a switch in my app. I added it in the storyboard (IUView with Switch class and Material module. I customed it in my viewcontroller but I don't know how to do the action on it.

I tried adding IBAction with the touch up inside event, but I have nothing when I touch it.

Thanks.

My code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit 
import Material

class SettingsVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var addCalendarSwitch: Switch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addCalendarSwitch.delegate = self
        addObserver()
        setStyle()
        setView()
        getStatusAddCalendar()
    }

    func getStatusAddCalendar(){
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "addToCalendar") == true 
        {
            addCalendarSwitch.isOn = true
        }
        else {
            addCalendarSwitch.isOn = false
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: SwitchDelegate {

    // utilise the delegate method
    func switchDidChangeState(control: Switch, state: SwitchState) {
        print("Switch changed state to: ", .on == state ? "on" : "off")
    }
}
```

[hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qBlC.png)

[screen of my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTAIc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the examples it seems it is using a delegate pattern.
https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/blob/master/Projects/Programmatic/Switch/Switch/ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Material

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // create an outlet and connect it from your storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: Switch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // use this outlet to assign the delegate
        mySwitch.delegate = self
    }
}

// conform to the protocol
extension ViewController: SwitchDelegate {

    // utilise the delegate method
    func switchDidChangeState(control: Switch, state: SwitchState) {
        print("Switch changed state to: ", .on == state ? "on" : "off")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I saw this, but I'm novice, and I don't know how to do this with my switch in the storyboard

Comment: I've updated the example. To access the switch from storyboard within your controller you need to create an `IBOutlet` and connect it. Then you can assign the delegate and provide the delegate methods as shown.

Comment: Ok thanks, I tried, but first, I have to make public the function switchDidChangeState " Method 'switchDidChangeState(control:state:)' must be declared public because it matches a requirement in public protocol 'SwitchDelegate' ", and if I put mySwitch.delegate = self, self is my view Controller and I have this error " Cannot assign value of type 'SettingsVC' to type 'SwitchDelegate?' "

Comment: Unfortunately without seeing any of your code it is hard to provide help. I've created a simple example with storyboard if you would like to review/compare your implementation. https://transfernow.net/279i98h0g14f

Comment: Thanks, I compared with my code and I think I have the same thing.
I've edit my query with my code.
With that code, I have the two issue I wrote before.

Comment: in your code you are doing `extension ViewController: SwitchDelegate {` - it should be like this instead `extension SettingsVC: SwitchDelegate {` as you are extending your custom class

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, I have other problem nothing happen when I touch the switch, but I try to find

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work in my view. It's a scrollview, in it there is a view and inside my switch.

Comment: I did similar setup again to compare https://transfernow.net/810fr2w1t6b3 - if you are able to share your project I could have a look...

Comment: Thanks, I can share my project, but i've added screenshot, tell me if you want more. I compare with your project but I can't find.

Comment: The project would be easier but to confirm; right now when you run the app you can see the switch but interaction (touch) does not work (does not toggle state)? If so I would check if any of the views in your hierarchy don't have `userInteractionEnabled` set to false.

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake, I can't share my project. You're right when I touch the switch nothing happens. I checked if `userInteractionEnabled` was set to false in a view but no.

Comment: And the switch is enabled `addCalendarSwitch.isEnabled = true` or in interface builder set to `default` or `on` right?

Comment: I am afraid I am out of options to help. I would suggest to try to simplify first (debug) by moving the switch into simpler view hierarchy and see if things work. Your view setup is IMHO a bit cumbersome as normally you would use table view or similar for this kind of layout.

Comment: Hi, so I found the problem, one of the parent's view had its height set to 0. This was made by the previous dev, and I didn't think about checking there.  Thanks for your help